# python character count problems

Tags: python, python-2.7, character-encoding

I'm trying to count a line 8 characters or less at a time and have it count how many times lower case "f" shows up. The value for how many times f shows up keeps showing zero. Text1.txt has lower case f"" one time on line 1 and 4 times on line 2.

```
with open("text1.txt","r+") as r:
while True:
      cCount = r.readlines(1)
      charSet = cCount.count("f")
      print charSet
      if not cCount:
          break
if charSet == 1:
    print("hello")
```

Where has my python logic failed.

Comment: Please properly intend your code.

Comment: Any errors? invalid results? Please explain the issue you're having

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
with open("text1.txt","r") as r:
    for line in r:
      print(line.count("f"))
```

this is the proper way to iterate over a file

EDIT: to change " fghfghf" to "3ghgh"

```
with open("text1.txt","r") as r:
    for line in r:
        if line.count("f")==3:
            print("3"+line.replace("f",""))
```

Comment: thank you user4624500 That help display how many on each line.


How can i set a variable to say ok f equals 3 on line 1 so replace f with three in the beginning of the line?

before python runs.-- fghfghf
after python runs.-- 3ghgh

Comment: I understand how to replace.("f","3") just seems I'm having issues stacking commands ontop of each other without having to start a new module. thanks again.